# How to use JMeter "assert" and "if"?

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

I wrote an HTTP request in JMeter which creates a Profile with a new Profile ID( which I am passing as a parameter in URL)

I want to generate a new profileID, in case if the given ProfileID is already existed.
How can I do this in JMeter?

currently test runs and passes with showing message that "Profile ID is already existed" as a result, in case of already existed ID.

Don't get Idea how to solve this issue .If I use "if controller", it will check pre-execution condition while I have a post-execution condition that the test runs and after getting this message "already existed" on page it should generate a new ID.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
While Controller with condition: ${IdExisted} != "Profile ID is already existed"
  HTTP Request generating random profile Id
    Regular Expression Extractor with reference name IdExisted, regex like "Profile ID is already existed", default value NOT_FOUND
```

You can carry out "Profile ID is already existed" to User Defined Variables to DRY this test.

But I think, you really don't need While Controller and Regular Expression Extractor. Maybe, you can just make HTTP Request generate more random Id.

To generate random id you can use function:

- [Random](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) if it should be an int, e.g. `${__Random(1, 100000000)}`
- [RandomString](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) if it should be a string, e.g. `${__RandomString(10)}`

Comment: Thanks Andrew , can u please elaborate it, can u give exact solution, where should I write it, How to generate random id? Please excuse my ignorance, I just started using Jmeter so I have no idea how to implement this solution.